# How to use "Simple Validation API" to validate Java Swing forms in Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, validation, netbeans

I have downloaded and installed the "Simple Validation" NetBeans Plug-in, but do not know how to use it, because I cannot find where is it present (in toolbox).


Can anyone kindly help me by telling how where can I find it and what are the steps to apply the validation on my form fields.


I also saw there was a Validation API JAR file and I downloaded and included it in my project. It provided 3 controls (or whatever I should say); "ValidationPanel", "ValidationUtils" and "Problems". I saw an example at a website & followed it. I dragged-and-dropped the "ValidationPanel" and wrote the code as shown in following code

```
final ValidationGroup group = validationPanel1.getValidationGroup();

group.add(txtUserName, Validators.REQUIRE_NON_EMPTY_STRING,
Validators.NO_WHITESPACE,
Validators.REQUIRE_VALID_INTEGER);
```

But it seems JAR file contains incomplete files or there may be other problem, because it gives error: cannot find symbol: variable "Validators"


I am sorry I think these are 2 questions, but kindly help me how to solve it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why bother for an external API, when you can use it inside Java, have a look at [Validation on Fields using JLayer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/jlayer.html#validation)

Comment: Why bother to make all the work yourself when you have a powerful, nice-looking robust and easy to implement API?

Answer (score 1):

You just want the "ValidationPanel".

It seems to be called "org.netbeans.validation.api.builtin.stringvalidation.StringValidators" now.

```
final ValidationGroup group = validationPanel1.getValidationGroup();

group.add(txtUserName, StringValidators.REQUIRE_NON_EMPTY_STRING,
StringValidators.NO_WHITESPACE,
StringValidators.REQUIRE_VALID_INTEGER);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing with those lines is  creating a validation group and adding a field with 3 validation rules but you still need a way to show that on screen.

Simple validation API provides 2 built-in UI helpers that I'm aware of, you can either use the `org.netbeans.validation.api.ui.swing.ValidationPanel` or the `org.netbeans.validation.api.ui.swing.SwingValidationGroup.createProblemLabel()`, otherwise you'll have to implement your own UI widget with the `org.netbeans.validation.api.ui.ValidationUI` interface.

- `ValidationPanel` creates a `JPanel` to hold your input controls plus ok and cancel buttons plus the label to show the error messages.
- On the other hand you have the `ProblemLabel` which is the easiest implementation and for me it works in most common cases, here's a little example:

  ```
      SwingValidationGroup group =  SwingValidationGroup.create();;

      group.add(txtUserName, Validators.REQUIRE_NON_EMPTY_STRING,
      Validators.NO_WHITESPACE,
      Validators.REQUIRE_VALID_INTEGER);

      JComponent validationLabel = group.createProblemLabel();
      contentPanel.add(validationLabel);
  ```

That way you have the `validationLabel` that you can add to any other container like a `JPanel` or to the form itself, in this case I have a panel named `contentPanel` that I attach the problem label to.

Hope this clarifies it a little bit as this is an awesome API with poor documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Did you `import` the required package?

Comment: Yes. When I wrote the code in NetBeans it gave same error for "ValidationGroup" class and when I clicked on a balloon on the left side of IDE it suggested me to import the package for it and when I clicked on it, it imported the apckage, but it does not suggest me to import package for "Validators"

Comment: @swdeveloper Are you sure there's even a class called `Validators`? I looked at the library but couldn't see one.

Comment: @ Tharwen that is the actual problem. The code example I downloaded (and shown above) uses it (i.e. Validators) as a class and there seem to be some constants which indicate which types of validation should be applied on that field, but NetBeans does not suggest any import for that. So I am also confused that if it is a class?

Comment: @ Tharwen following is the link which I had seen the code from: http://java.dzone.com/news/how-quickly-add-validation

Comment: I saw that already, and I didn't see a class called Validators.